# How can I remove missing values and enable a logistic regression to appear?

Tags: r, ggplot2, logistic-regression

I'm very new to R, I'm using a dataset (ESS) to model likelihood of wishing to leave the EU (leaveEU) by age band (age_cat). I made the age category variable by recoding the age category that was in the dataset which contained each age as one value instead of grouping them. I did that like this:

```
ESS$age_cat <- cut(ESS$agea, c(13, 25, 35, 45, 55, 65, 75, 120))

ESS$age_cat <- as.factor(ESS$age_cat)
```

The plot code is like this:

```
ggplot(data = ESS, aes(x = age_cat, y = leaveEU)) +

geom_jitter(height = 0.05, width = 0.1) +

stat_smooth(method = "glm",

method.args = list(family = "binomial"))
```

If I put the original age variable in it produces what I would like

But if I use the age category variable it does not produce a logistic regression line and adds a column at the
end which has the missing values in it.

How do I resolve this?

Apologies if I have not posted this in the correct way, I will try and amend it if so

Trying to add a logistic regression line to a plot with a new variable but it will not produce it

```
Example data:

> head(ESS$agea) 
[1] 43 67 40 63 71 64
> head(ESS)
# A tibble: 6 × 7,904
  ess9_id  cntry ess9_…¹ regunit nuts1 nuts2 nuts3 name 
  <chr>    <chr> <chr>   <dbl+l> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 AT00000… AT    AT22    2 [NUT… AT2   AT22  ""    ESS9…
2 AT00000… AT    AT21    2 [NUT… AT2   AT21  ""    ESS9…
3 AT00000… AT    AT33    2 [NUT… AT3   AT33  ""    ESS9…
4 AT00000… AT    AT21    2 [NUT… AT2   AT21  ""    ESS9…
5 AT00000… AT    AT32    2 [NUT… AT3   AT32  ""    ESS9…
6 AT00000… AT    AT21    2 [NUT… AT2   AT21  ""    ESS9…
# … with 7,896 more variables: essround <dbl>,
#   edition <chr>, proddate <chr>, idno <dbl>,
#   nwspol <dbl>, netusoft <dbl+lbl>, netustm <dbl>,
#   ppltrst <dbl+lbl>, pplfair <dbl+lbl>,
#   pplhlp <dbl+lbl>, polintr <dbl+lbl>,
#   psppsgva <dbl+lbl>, actrolga <dbl+lbl>,
#   psppipla <dbl+lbl>, cptppola <dbl+lbl>, …
# ℹ Use `colnames()` to see all variable names
> head(ESS$age_cat)
[1] (35,45] (65,75] (35,45] (55,65] (65,75] (55,65]
7 Levels: (13,25] (25,35] (35,45] (45,55] ... (75,120]
> head(ESS$leaveEU)
<labelled<double>[6]>: Would vote for [country] to remain member of European Union or leave, United Kin
[1] NA NA NA NA NA NA

Labels:
 value                                 label
     1 Remain a member of the European Union
     2              Leave the European Union
    33     Would submit a blank ballot paper
    44          Would spoil the ballot paper
    55       Would not vote in EU referendum
    65       Not eligible/registered to vote
```

Comment: @Edward sorry that wasn't supposed to be in the post I had just been trying to fix it with that but it hadn't worked

Comment: No problem. :)  It's difficult to know without the data. What is the range of age?

Comment: @Edward the range of the age is 15-90

Comment: Welcome to SO! It helps reproduce the problem when the post includes a data set.
An effective way to include one is `dput()`.
Run dput, then paste the output into your question.
See [rdocumentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/dput).
If your object is a vector, matrix, table, or data frame and is large,
`object |> head() |> dput()` will help give manageably sized output.

Comment: Try using `aes(x = as.numeric(age_cat)`...

Comment: @Isaiah Okay thanks, I've added head to the data not sure if that is enough to see though

Comment: @edward Thanks a lot, that worked. Do you know how I can change the column labels to use their labels rather than numbers in the graph?

Comment: Try `scale_x_continuous(breaks=1:7, labels=levels(ESS$age_cat))`